# Android app crashs after changing package name

Tags: java, android

I changed the package name of my app and its now crashing. In the manifest file I changed the package name and in the code as well. 
Thats what logcat says:

```
01-19 21:38:47.466: W/ResourceType(13905): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
01-19 21:38:47.476: W/dalvikvm(13905): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400205a0)
01-19 21:38:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(13905): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 10
01-19 21:38:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(13905): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
01-19 21:38:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:901)
01-19 21:38:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:826)
01-19 21:38:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:808)
01-19 21:38:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at com.appboss.min3d.parser.ObjParser.parse(ObjParser.java:60)
01-19 21:38:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at com.appboss.mercurysim.Rocket.initScene(Rocket.java:325)
01-19 21:38:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at com.appboss.min3d.core.Scene.init(Scene.java:272)
01-19 21:38:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at com.appboss.min3d.core.Renderer.onSurfaceCreated(Renderer.java:74)
01-19 21:38:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1348)
01-19 21:38:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(13905):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
```

Comment: Do complete uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Has anything changed in `res/` ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you change your classname in the manifest as well?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do these steps:

1. **clean** the project (`Project` > `Clean...`)
2. **fix project properties** (right click on project in `Package Explorer` > `Android Tools` > `Fix Project Properties`)
3. **delete all `import android.R`** if present
4. check for `.getIdentifier(resourceName, defType, "your_old_package_that_is_now_changed");` and fix it with the new package name

Comment: didn't work :/. The message on the phone doesn't show long but i think there was the old name on it o.O I restarted the phone and searched for the old name in the project. But there isn't this name

Comment: lol, the app has the same name as the old App. But i changed this as well and that worked up to now o.O what am i doing wrong?

Comment: if you have something like `android:label="@string/app_name"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` then your app name is in `\res\values\string.xml`. But why now you are interested in the app name? This is not the cause of your problem..

Comment: ok, thank you. The app can't open the resources. what do you think i can do?

Comment: oh sorry I'm such an idiot -.-. I didn't changed the path to the resources. Eclipse don't show me that.

Comment: Remember step 4 I've just been through the same exercise, I suggest emphasizing this step!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this may have caused a discrepancy between the package name, and the class name, or at least the package declaration. If you just renamed the file, then the code isn't matching. And if you did fix the code, there may be some other method that is expecting the package with its old name.